# Run Docker image without any root access

Tags: linux, docker, root, container, podman

Think of yourself working on a managed Linux server, just using a normal user identity, without any way to use root at all.
Lazy and paranoid system administrators refuse to install any new packages.

Docker, Podman, and other container runtimes are not currently installed on the system.

In this case, is there any way for me to run the Docker/OCI image?
I know there will be many limitations in rootless docker, but I can accept these limitations.

Comment: There are prerequisites even for a total user solution: Some Linux distributions just disable user namespaces by default. Check that: `/sbin/sysctl user.max_user_namespaces` doesn't return 0 and (if the patch for this entry exists) `/sbin/sysctl kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone` returns 1 or doesn't exist. With these, you can run a very very limited container-like setup. If in addition the privileged commands `newuidmap` and `newgidmap` are available, much more can be made possible. So what do you have available?

Answer (score 0):

If your environment is extremely rigid, you may still try the
following methods:

- If you have any virtual-machine product, such as Hyper-V or
  Virtualbox, you may create a VM where you're the administrator
- You may also do the same with WSL, if already enabled on the
  computer
- You could try to use
  [docker-toolbox-portable](https://github.com/portapps/docker-toolbox-portable?tab=readme-ov-file)
  as explained in the article
  [Docker Toolbox portable](https://portapps.io/app/docker-toolbox-portable/)
- You may try to install
  [Install Docker Engine from binaries](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/binaries/),
  if you have the required prerequisites.